# Mapbox GL JS / Maplibre : Style cluster regarding child properties

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I have a geojson dataset with a property "status" that has the value active or inactive. From this dataset, I want to create a clusters layer. These clusters should be of a different color depending on the majority value. If there's a majority of active, color blue, otherwise color red.

Regarding the documentation, I have to set a property in the clusters layer to have something like this:

```
this.map.addSource('projects', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: myData,
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 11,
        clusterRadius: 20,
        clusterProperties: {
          dominantStatus: [Expression that returns dominant value in status attribut],
        },
      });
```

I have absolutely no idea how to write an expression that returns this type of result. Does anyone know how?